# Como crear versiones de un proyecto con Git

Tags: git

Estoy actualizando un proyecto que habia realizado hace unos meses y me recomendaron usar Git para el control de versiones. Vi algunos tutoriales para aprender a utlizarlo pero no logro entenderlo bien.

Hasta ahora hice un `get init` en Proyecto-v1.0

```
tienda
  |__ index.php
  |__ include
         |__ config.php
         |__ class.tienda.php
         |__ class.pagosv1.php
  |__ css
       |__ main.css
```

Ahora tengo modificar los archivos para crear Proyecto-v1.1 lo cual: tengo que hacer otro `git init`?, tengo que crear otro directorio y copiar los archivos para hacer la version 1.1?

Disculpen la pregunta, pero no logro entender bien como se trabaja en un solo proyecto varias versiones.

Gracias

Comment: Te refieres a crear un nuevo branch de trabajo? Para ello puedes utilizar `git checkout -b development` o lo que quieres es hacer un nuevo release de la aplicación?

Comment: Quiero ir versionando el proyecto, si vien el sistema de pago tiene cambio oficiales de la api, tengo que modificar varios archivos y no solo son esos, tambien hay cambio de disenio. Entonces pasaria a la version 2 o 1.2 del proyecto

Answer (score 3):

El potencial de **git** es que el control de versiones lo maneja internamente la herramienta. Y con control de versiones no sólo se refiere a versiones finales, sino tambien al historial de cambios (git te puede permitir volver al momento de tiempo en el que cambiaste tan solo una ',').

La idea con **git** no es cambiarle el nombre al archivo para denotar la version en la que te encuentras (1.1, 1.2, etc.), sino que el archivo se llame siempre igual (en tu caso: Proyecto)

Ahora bien cada versionado que vos hagas debes "commitearlo" para generar ese "versionado" que buscás. Todo lo que vos hagas commit va a ser parte de ese historial. Como se hace eso:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Que cambios hay en esta version"
$ git push
```

El `push` va a hacer que tu "versionado" no solo quede localmente y que se pueda perder solo en tu maquina, lo va a dejar registrado en el repositorio remoto.

De esta forma si uno quiere volver a una versión puede simplemente "pararse" sobre un commit (que no es mas que una imagen de lo que era tu proyecto en ese entonces) y así vuelves a una versión antigua sin perder los cambios nuevos. Como se hace esto?

```
$ git log --oneline
```

Copiar primeros 8 caracteres hexadecimales (SHA identificador del commit abreviado)

```
$ git checkout <SHA abreviado>
```

Y para volver a donde estabas

```
$ git checkout <branch anterior, por ej: master>
```

El uso de los branchs para llevar un versionado no es completamente necesario. Es muy útil para proyectos grandes en los que participan muchas personas. Es recomendable siempre tener una rama `master` que tenga versiones estables y trabajar sobre otras ramas mientras se desarrolla.

Te recomiendo esta [guia](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.es.html) que en su momento me ayudo.

Comment: -1 por decir "commitearlo"! Jejeje, nomentiras, +1 por el esfuerzo en hacer una respuesta completa